# Rails + Spreadsheet gem: How to push row into sheet without index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I have to loop through an array and I'm not sure which row I'm going to start at since that varies:

```
def add_data
  @sheet = @workbook.create_worksheet
  responses.each do |response|
    # I want something like @sheet.rows << [response.id]
  end
end
```

I'm looking through the docs but all the examples given use a specified row index: http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html

How would I push an array of values to the next row in the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just dug into the classes themselves and came up with a solution... the documentation kinda whomps:

```
@sheet.insert_row(@sheet.last_row_index + 1, ["hey", "cool"])
```